# how to convert a string to mulidimensional array?

Tags: jquery, vb.net

The values are passed as a string:

```
Dim strInput as string  
strInput = "[{'Date':'2014-8','A':'561265.00','B':'6500.00'},{'Date':'2014-9','A':'14000.00','B':'459434.00'}]"
```

Comment: Ok what will be your expected output?

Comment: it seems like json. Convert it to JSON and than array.

Answer (score 0):

you can define the JSON Object by replace single quotes to double as below snippet

```
   var strInput = [{"Date":"2014-8","A":"561265.00","B":"6500.00"},{"Date":"2014-9","A":"14000.00","B":"459434.00"}];
```

and can access the values as

```
strInput[0].Date
```